# MySQL multiple PK

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am facing a problem while designing a MySQL database.
I have five tables:

1. PROFESSOR
2. GROUP
3. CLASSROOM
4. SESSION
5. COURSE_SESSION

While COURSE_SESSION columns are other tables primary keys:

```
|PROFESSOR_ID|GROUP_ID|CLASSROOM_ID|SESSION_ID |
| 1          |1       |3           |1          |
| 2          |2       |4           |1          |
```

Knowing that table SESSION has startTime and endTime columns.

I want to make sure that when I insert twice:

1. The same PROFESSOR_ID with the same SESSION_ID
2. Or, the same GROUP_ID with the same SESSION_ID
3. Or, the same CLASSROOM_ID with the same SESSION_ID

The action is restricted.

Is that possible using primary key constraints? or this design is invalid for my purpose ?

Comment: You can define only one primary key but multiple unque keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use unique constraints (or unique indexes, which do basically the same thing):

```
alter table course_session add constraint unq_course_session_ps
    unique (professor_id, session_id);

alter table course_session add constraint unq_course_session_gs
    unique (group_id, session_id);

alter table course_session add constraint unq_course_session_cs
    unique (classroom_id, session_id);
```

You can also put the unique constraint in the table definition itself....